# Can't make nitrogen set a wallpaper

Tags: 14.04, gnome, desktop-background

I've got 2 monitors so I want to use nitrogen to set a different wallpaper for each one.

I just made a clean Ubuntu install and installed gnome-shell and ubuntu-gnome-desktop. After that I installed nitrogen, and tried to change the wallpaper but it does nothing.

If If I toogle the "Icons on Desktop" option on the Tweak Tool it shows the wallpapers I selected on nitrogen for less than a second, and then back to the default wallpaper.

There used to be an option to disable the handling of the desktop by the file manager so nitrogen could do it, but I can't find it. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install dconf-editor if it's not installed yet:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor`
3. In `dconf-editor`, explore to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/`
4. Unmark the show-desktop-icons option.

[image]

Please note that on (at least) Ubuntu 13.10-14.10, using Nitrogen can cause desktop freezes ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/variety/+bug/1394770 , https://github.com/l3ib/nitrogen/issues/51 )

Answer (score 0):

The option has been renamed to "Icons on Desktop". Flip this to off to find your background as set by Nitrogen.